# Getting Errors in Flutter while creating first app app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am just trying to launch the first basic created code on flutter which is the counter button on the screen, now if I try to Debug it then it always gets messed up in all sorts of errors. Currently, the error is this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Shaffan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6697cfdd11e9fefb1f002637ca986f5e\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                                       
   > Failed to transform annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Shaffan\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation\1.1.0\e3a6fb2f40e3a3842e6b7472628ba4ce416ea4c8\annotation-1.1.0.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:     
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\Shaffan\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\aa48591568018e27fbbfd58c8ab4f3a5\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 30s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I'm using Java JDK 15 version

Comment: try to do File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Usually this is caused by something unwanted being cached, there are two ways to fix this usually:

1. Run `flutter clean` inside terminal from the root of your flutter project. Restart your emulator and rebuild the project.
2. If that doesn't work, close Android Studio, Navigate to your gradle cache, `C:/Users/YourUser/.gradle/caches` and delete everything inside, then reopen Android Studio and try again.

Comment: The error was due to the caches, Thank you for the help!